# In a xe:dataView how to code the summary facet to show/hide the detail facet?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

By default the summary column adds a link to open the underlying document as specified in the dataView's pageName property.  I have a use-case where I want to keep the application in the dataView, and not open any "documentXPage".

I know this could be done in a repeat, but there are other parts/functionality of the dataView that work nicely for the application, so ideally I'm just looking to override the default behavior of the summaryColumn.

To override the link behavior I added the summary column as a facet, instead of a property, as in:

```
<xp:this.facets>
    <xp:panel xp:key="summary" id="summaryPanel">
        <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField3">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var custName = viewEntry.getColumnValue("Customer");
return "<h4>"+custName+"</h4>"}]]>
                   </xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
    </xp:panel>
    <xp:panel xp:key="detail" id="detailsPanel" readonly="true">
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[{javascript:
viewEntry.getDocument().getItemValueString("Address") + ",      " +
viewEntry.getDocument().getItemValueString("City") + ", " +
viewEntry.getDocument().getItemValueString("State")}]]>
                    </xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
   </xp:panel>
<\xp:this.facets>
```

How do I code my summary facet to show/hide the details facet when clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Mikael in Domino 9 the toggleDetailVisible function does not seem to work. Based on a suggestion from Brad Balassaitis I got it working by getting a handle to the twistie object and clicking it.

```
var myid = "#{id:link3}";
var parts = myid.split(":");
var outparts = [];
for(var idx=0; idx<parts.length-1; idx++){
    outparts[idx] = parts[idx];
}
outparts[outparts.length-1] += "_shimg";
var bid = outparts.join(":");

var btn = document.getElementById(bid);
btn.click();
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the setting detailsOnClient.

If that is set to true, you should be able to use CSJS to set display to "block" or "none" and you should be able to work out the ID of the element you need to change, using getComponent("dataView1").getRowIndex() (assuming your dataView has the ID dataView1)

This is also the key to doing the same if detailsOnClient is false. The following code will work.

```
var idex=getComponent("dataView1").getRowIndex();
getComponent("dataView1").toggleDetailVisible(@Text(idex+1));
```

You're basically getting a handle on the current rowIndex (which starts at 0), adding 1 to get the row to toggle and converting it to text. The DataView control has a method toggleDetailVisible(String) which is used to do the toggle.